# Global variable in another file can't be accessed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this has been asked a ton of times, but I've checked several other questions and answers and I'm still no closer to solving my problem.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="GitUserSearch">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Github user search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap_css_overrides/bootstrap_overrides.css">
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="js/secrets.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/gitUserSearchController.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="GitUserSearchController as searchCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchCtrl.searchTerm" ng-change="searchCtrl.doSearch()" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="searchCtrl.doSearch()">Search</button>
      </form>
      <br>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li ng-repeat="user in searchCtrl.searchResult.items">
          <img ng-src="{{user.avatar_url}}&s=50">
          <a ng-href="{{user.html_url}}">{{user.login}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

js/secrets.js:

```
githubToken = "longGithubTokenThatICannotShareHerePublicly";
```

secrets.js is in .gitignore.

js/gitUserSearchController.js:

```
githubUserSearch.controller('GitUserSearchController', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  var self = this;

  var searchResource = $resource('https://api.github.com/search/users/');
  var githubToken = githubToken;

  self.doSearch = function() {
    self.searchResult = searchResource.get(
      { q: self.searchTerm, access_token: githubToken }
    );
  };
}]);
```

When I run the app I can see, using the browser's inspections tools, that the http request is being made *without* the `githubToken` string.

When I hard-code the githubToken string into the gitUserSearchController, instead of trying to make it use the supposed `githubToken` global variable, the http request is made perfectly with the GitHub token present , as it should be.

So it seems to be a problem with how I have the files setup and how the variables are being declared and accessed.

Repo [here](https://github.com/Yorkshireman/angular-github).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var githubToken = githubToken;
```

You're defining a new local variable that "hides" the global by the same name.  For any given symbol name, the local scope is searched before the global scope is searched so a local variable with the same name as a global essentially "hides" the global.

Plus, due to "hoisting" of all `var` definitions in Javascript to the top of the function scope in which they are declared, your above line of code is actually treated like this:

```
var githubToken;
githubToken = githubToken;
```

So, you can further see why it's not doing what you want it to do.

Change the name of the local variable to be something different or don't even define a new variable, just use the global directly since there appears to be no reason to assign to a local variable anyway.

Comment: Thankyou! I actually realised this myself due to the 'rubber duck effect' after posting, but I didn't know why exactly and you've explained it really well so cheers.